# Telerik report only have PDF option, no Excel and Word option

Tags: c#, telerik, report

When I generate Telerik Report , only Export PDF is available. Even I set the config of docx and xlsx to true. Here is my config in web config.

```
<configSections>
    <section name="Telerik.Reporting" type="Telerik.Reporting.Configuration.ReportingConfigurationSection, Telerik.Reporting, Version=8.2.14.1027, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=A9D7983DFCC261BE" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
  </configSections>



<Telerik.Reporting>
<AssemblyReferences>
<add name="BusinessObject.Client" version="1.0.0.0" />
                        <add name="BusinessObject.Client" version="1.0.0.0" />
</AssemblyReferences>
    <Extensions>
      <Render>
        <Extension name="PDF" visible="true"></Extension>
        <Extension name="XLS" visible="false"></Extension>
        <Extension name="CSV" visible="false"></Extension>
        <Extension name="RTF" visible="false"></Extension>
        <Extension name="XPS" visible="false"></Extension>
        <Extension name="DOCX" visible="true"></Extension>
        <Extension name="XLSX" visible="true"></Extension>
        <Extension name="PPTX" visible="false"></Extension>
        <Extension name="MHTML" visible="false"></Extension>
        <Extension name="IMAGE" visible="false"></Extension>
        <Extension name="HTML5" visible="false"></Extension>
        <Extension name="HTML5Interactive" visible="false"></Extension>
      </Render>
    </Extensions>
  </Telerik.Reporting>
```

I am using Telerik for ASP.Net

Comment: Could be have the element (Grid, etc..) definition that have only, the pdf option? Many of them have property for the avaidable export option. May you also confirm wich version of telerik we are adressing (ASP.NET AJAX, etc..)? And [edit] those information in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Word, PowerPoint and Excel [rendering extensions](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/designing-reports-considerations-overview.html) require
> Telerik.Reporting.OpenXmlRendering.dll and [Open XML SDK 2.0 for
> Microsoft Office](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/installation-deploying-openxml.html) (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll v.2.0.5022.0 or
> above). If you want to avoid the installation of Open XML SDK you can
> copy the required DocumentFormat.OpenXml assembly from C:\Program
> Files (x86)\Telerik\Reporting {version}\Examples\bin folder.

For more information on the topic check out the [Deploying Web Applications](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/installation-deploying-on-web-application.html) help article.

link: [telerik.com/forums/report-exporting-word-excel-ets](https://telerik.com/forums/report-exporting-word-excel-et)